# Команды discord.py перестали работать

Tags: python, discord.py

Команды discord.py одно время отлично работали, потом я запустил бота и всё перестало работать. Ошибок в консоли нет, а client.event работает исправно.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def start_event(member):
    role_alfa = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 822908874561814528)
    role_delta = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 822908916445741076)
    a = [role_alfa, role_delta]
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            await member.add_roles(random.choice(a))
    print('Ивент начался!')
```

Весь код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from config import settings
from discord.utils import get
import random


intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "~", intents = discord.Intents.all())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Вход выполнен {client.user.name}')
    await client.change_presence(status = discord.Status.idle)


@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send('Вы ввели неправильную комманду, если вы их не знаете введите ~help')


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role_alfa = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 822908874561814528)
    role_delta = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 822908916445741076)
    a = [role_alfa, role_delta]
    await member.add_roles(random.choice(a))


@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def start_event(member):
    role_alfa = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 822908874561814528)
    role_delta = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 822908916445741076)
    a = [role_alfa, role_delta]
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            await member.add_roles(random.choice(a))
    print('Ивент начался!')


@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def break_event(member):
    role_alfa = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 822908874561814528)
    role_delta = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 822908916445741076)
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            await member.remove_roles(role_alfa)
            await member.remove_roles(role_delta)
    print('Ивент закончен!')


@start_event.error
async def start_event_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f'Ээ оло, недостаточно прав, {ctx.author.mention}')


@break_event.error
async def break_event_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f'Ээ оло, недостаточно прав, {ctx.author.mention}')


client.run("No, token i won't give you ^_^")
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен, но думаю что вместо параметра **member** надо написать **member: discord.Member**

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def start_event(member: discord.Member):
    role_alfa = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 822908874561814528)
    role_delta = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 822908916445741076)
    a = [role_alfa, role_delta]
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            await member.add_roles(random.choice(a))
    print('Ивент начался!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не выдаёт ошибку, попробуй убрать **on_command_error**

```
# @client.event
# async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    # if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        # await ctx.send('Вы ввели неправильную комманду, если вы их не знаете введите ~help')
```

Comment: не знаю, надо ли убирать решётки перед строками кода. потому оставил.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, тут много лишнего:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "~", intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

Оставьте только это:

```
client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "~", intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

Добавьте в аргументы `ctx`

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def start_event(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    role_alfa = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 822908874561814528)
    role_delta = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 822908916445741076)
    a = [role_alfa, role_delta]
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            await member.add_roles(random.choice(a))
    print('Ивент начался!')
```